# PostgreSQL - DB user should only be allowed to call functions

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions, sql-injection, user-permissions

Currently I'm using PostgreSQL for my application. Since I am trying to put every SQL that contains a transaction (i.e. insert, update, delete) in a function, I stumbled upon this problem:

Is it possible that a database user may only be allowed to call functions and Select-Statements while he can not call SQL-Statements which contains a transaction? By "call functions" I mean any function. Regardless if it contains a transaction or not.

I already tried to create a user which can only call functions and Select-Statements. But I always end up with an error, when calling functions which contains transactions. For what I understand a dbuser needs write permissions if a he calls a function which uses an insert, update or delete statement.

Am I missing something? Is this scenario really not possible? Security-wise this would be really great because you pretty much prevent SQL-injection in the first place.

Comment: It will not prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Functions do not "contain transactions". They are embedded in a transaction themselves automatically.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no "privilege on `SELECT`". All you need is the privilege to `EXECUTE` functions. Function can also be declared with [`SECURITY DEFINER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) to inherit all privileges of the owner. To keep possible privilege escalation at a minimum, make a daemon role with only the necessary privileges own functions in question, not a superuser!

#### Recipe

As superuser ...

Create a non-superuser role `myuser`.

```
CREATE ROLE myuser PASSWORD ...;
```

Create a group role `mygroup` and make `myuser` member in it.

```
CREATE ROLE mygroup;  -- NOLOGIN ?
GRANT mygroup TO myuser;
```

You may want to add more users just like `myuser` later.

Do **not grant any privileges at all** to `myuser`.
Only grant these to `mygroup`:

- `GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO mygroup;`
- `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO mygroup;`
- `GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION foo() TO mygroup;`

Revoke all privileges from `PUBLIC` that `myuser` shouldn't have.

```
REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema FROM public;
```

There may be more. [I quote the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html)

> PostgreSQL grants default privileges on some types of objects to
> `PUBLIC`. No privileges are granted to PUBLIC by default on tables,
> columns, schemas or tablespaces. For other types, the default
> privileges granted to PUBLIC are as follows: `CONNECT` and `CREATE TEMP TABLE` for databases; `EXECUTE` privilege for functions; and `USAGE`
> privilege for languages. The object owner can, of course, `REVOKE` both
> default and expressly granted privileges. (For maximum security, issue
> the `REVOKE` in the same transaction that creates the object; then there
> is no window in which another user can use the object.) Also, these
> initial default privilege settings can be changed using the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` command.

Create a **daemon role** to *own* relevant functions.

```
CREATE ROLE mydaemon;
```

Grant only privileges necessary to execute these functions to `mydaemon`, (including `EXECUTE ON FUNCTION` to allow another function to be called). Again, you can use group roles to bundle privileges and grant them to `mydaemon`

```
GRANT bundle1 TO mydaemon;
```

In addition you can use [**`DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) to automatically grant certain privileges for future objects to a bundle or the daemon directly:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES    TO bundle1;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT USAGE  ON SEQUENCES TO bundle1;
```

This applies only to the role it is executed for. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

> If `FOR ROLE` is omitted, the current role is assumed.

To also cover pre-existing objects in the schema (see [rob's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867175/postgresql-db-user-should-only-be-allowed-to-call-functions/15868268?noredirect=1#comment75197559_15868268)):

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES    IN SCHEMA public TO bundle1;
GRANT USAGE  ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO bundle1;
```

Make `mydaemon` own relevant functions. Could look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo();
  ...
SECURITY DEFINER SET search_path = myschema, pg_temp;

ALTER FUNCTION foo() OWNER TO mydaemon;
REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION foo() FROM public;
GRANT  EXECUTE ON FUNCTION foo() TO mydaemon;
GRANT  EXECUTE ON FUNCTION foo() TO mygroup;
-- possibly others ..
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. I was not aware that something like `SECURITY DEFINER` exist since I'm fairly new to functions in SQL. Thank you! :)

Comment: not sure if I missed a step by I also needed to grant access to the mydaemon for TABLES (I did not use the bundle1 group). `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO mydaemonf

Comment: @rob: I had only covered `future objects` in my recipe. I added pre-existing objects to the mix now to address your point.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter what would happen if the `SECURITY DEFINER` function were owned by `postgres` and end users were not able to log on with `postgres`? Would such be OK?

Comment: @IamIC; `postgres` being a superuser, any such function has unlimited privileges. Be *very* sure that 1: the function only does what it's supposed to; 2: execution is restricted to competent roles; 3: there is no security problem in the code that might be exploited. Rather, don't do it at all in security-sensitive DBs. Whether anybody can log in with the `postgres` role or not, is not relevant to this issue.

Comment: I understand. I suppose one could also assign ownership to the schema in scope (not `public`) and revoke relationship rights as needed.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, sorry to ask here... I posted a related question and no one has answered it. If you have some time and are feeling a little brave, would you mind taking a look at it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576019/figuring-out-grant-and-revoke-for-multiple-roles-schemas-in-postgresql-10

Comment: This is a wonderful answer, and meets the needs of a project that I am working on.