# Postgres Grant CRUD on DATABASE to USER

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I have an application which uses a postgres database. I have a superadmin user. Now I need two more users: One "application-user" with CRUD-privileges and one with ALTER and CREATE-privileges (to apply migrations). These are all users I need, because the application has its own User-Access management and it is not at all planned to change that.

I want something like: `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON DATABASE MyDatabase TO myuser`

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918367/grant-privileges-for-a-particular-database-in-postgresql/24923877#24923877) that postgres provides pre defined roles. This is good - but these roles apply globally (as pointed out in one comment). MyDatabase is on `public` schema which becomes problematic because some system tables are on public too - and I don't want myuser to be able to read from or write to these.

I'd be fine with `GRANT pg_read_all_data, pg_write_all_data ON DATABASE MyDatabase TO myuser` but this doesn't work.

As I'll not change these privileges often I'd even be fine with `GRANT pg_read_all_data ON MyDatabase.MyTable TO myuser` as well. But this doesn't work either.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: `pg_read_all_data`  most certainly does not "apply on schema" - it's a global role. A user with that role can read data from any table.  I also have the impression that you are confusing the terms "database" and "schema".

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I've updated my question. I'm not sure if I'm confusing those terms - but I'm very sure that I want to grant privileges on Database-Level not on schema level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `ALTER` and `CREATE` privileges in PostgreSQL. The database user that should be able to run `ALTER` and `CREATE` statements will have to be the owner of the database objects. If you already have objects owned by a different user, you will have to change the ownership.

For the other user, you will have to grant privileges on each and every object. Privileges on the database won't help – there is no inheritance of privileges between objects. Don't forget to grant `USAGE` on the schemas.

I recommend that you create more schemas than `public`. If you have a separate schema for your application's objects, you can use statements like

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myapp TO someuser;
```