# SECURITY DEFINER - privileges of the function's creator, or owner?

Tags: postgresql, execute, postgresql-9.4, database-security

Postgres's [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createfunction.html) indicate that functions defined with SECURITY DEFINER run with privileges of the user who **created** it.

However other sources, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867175/postgresql-db-user-should-only-be-allowed-to-call-functions) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46833/what-are-the-privileges-required-to-execute-a-trigger-function-in-postgresql-8-4), claim it is the privileges of the **owner** of the function.

Which is correct?

(for 9.4+)

Comment: The user creating the function is the owner (unless you change the owner manually)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   But that's the whole point... generally, when I create a new function, I'm logged in with very high privileges. I want the users who run those functions to have limited (sometimes, SELECT only) privileges.

Comment: Then leave out the security definer (that's the whole point of `security definer`:  give unprivileged  users access to privileged things)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Right, `security definer` lets users "borrow" some elevated privileges only while executing the function. Let's say I have a function that INSERTs data, that I want a restricted user to be able to execute. I would prefer the user to temporarily emulate a function "owner" who can only SELECT and INSERT, rather than a superuser who can create functions and also DELETE, TRUNCATE, UPDATE, etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Usually (initially) the creator is the owner. However, if the owner of the function has been changed, `security definer` applies to the new owner. Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alterfunction.html):

> new_owner - The new owner of the function. Note that if the function is marked SECURITY DEFINER, it will subsequently execute as the new owner.